# Change date format in OpenERP

Tags: openerp

OpenERP defaults to using the MM/DD/YYYY in the GTK client, but I want to use YYYY-MM-DD. How can I change it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [this forum thread](http://www.openobject.com/forum/topic9852.html), the setting is in the user preferences, but it's still a bit buggy (as of OpenERP 5.0.14).

First, an administrator needs to add a new language choice.

- From the Administration menu, choose Translations: Application Terms: Languages.
- Click the New button
- Switch to the form view to see all the extra fields, including date format.
- Fill in the date format you want, give the language a unique name and code, and check the Translatable check box.
- Click the save button.

Next, the users have to choose the new language. Either they can do it themselves through the User: Preferences menu item, or an administrator can do it for them through the Administration: Users: Users menu item.

Things that don't work in OpenERP 5.0.14:

- Changing the date format on the default English language entry. It seems to get ignored, except maybe in reports.
- Double clicking on a language entry doesn't bring up the form view, and neither does clicking the New button. You have to explicitly click the Form button.