# Change date format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in OpenERP

Tags: openerp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change date format in OpenERP](https://superuser.com/questions/189134/change-date-format-in-openerp)

Change date format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in OpenERP

Comment: Dupe http://superuser.com/questions/189134/change-date-format-in-openerp

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find all the details you need in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/189134/2004).